# Are there any books or articles on experiences of inventors after their invention?

Tags: inventor, reference, book

**Background**

I wonder how inventors experience things after they've invented something. Some might patent it, and either start a business or benefit from the royalties of licensing the patent. Others might not patent their invention.

I'd like to know whether any studies have been performed on the experiences of such inventors after their invention, which detail how content they were with their decisions. I am curious as to whether inventors actually enjoy starting a business and/or patenting their inventions, or whether other avenues have proven more satisfactory to them.

Although I have found the following [relevant article](https://scholarlycommons.pacific.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1162&context=esob-facarticles), it is not quite what I have in mind. It doesn't go into whether inventors were happy with their decisions surrounding their inventions.

**Question**: are there any books or articles on the experiences of inventors after their inventions?

Comment: Have you reviewed the references from the cited paper?

Comment: @EricS No not yet - good idea

Comment: Find a relevant paper, which you have, review its bibliography, and iterate. Some people use citation managers to help organize this. Unfortunately, I know of no relevant papers.